# Knowing that the norm of a vector of AB is 4 and a point A(1,2), how do you find B?

Tags: vectors

Basically the title.

Knowing the vector norm AB and the point A how do I find B?

Comment: It is $(1,2)+4(c,d)$ where $(c,d)$ is any vector with $c^{2}+d^{2}=1$.

Comment: You can't. $B$ could lie at any point on a circle of radius $4$ (the norm of $\overline{AB}$) centered at $A$ (the point $(1,2)$).

Without further information, you can only say it lies on that circle and thus $B$ could be infinitely many points.

Comment: It's an exercise on my math book. The answer is B(1+4,2), which I don't understand why. @EeveeTrainer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you mean the absolute value of $$|\vec{AB}|=4$$ if so then we get
$$\sqrt{(x_B-1)^2+(y_B-2)^2}=4$$

Comment: Right. You'd end up with two variables: y and x. How can you solve the equation then?

Comment: You can only say that $$(x_B-1)^2+(y_B-2)^2=16$$, this is a circle.

Comment: It's an exercise on my math book. The answer is B(1+4,2), which I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes $$B(5;2)$$ is only one solution, since $$(5-1)^2+(2-2)^2=16$$

Comment: Maybe some additional conditions are lost.